# Do I need to plumb my walls?

Tags: walls, wood, engineering, frame, leveling

I'm building a small room and I do not have the option of leveling the floor, which is currently at about a 1-2° slant parallel to the 14 ft walls and perpendicular to the 12 ft walls. The walls are only about 84" (7') tall and the ceiling will only need to support about 40 lbs of hanging mass (acoustic panels). The room is about 12' by 14' and the top of the walls would overhang the base by 1-2 inches on the 12' side, if my math is correct. I plan on sheathing the frames with 3/4 plywood and 5/8 drywall.  the studs are 16" apart and will all be cross braced.

if i plumb the two walls parallel to the slope, they will not be square, and the only door, which is at the bottom of the slope and opens inward, may get stuck on the rubber weather stripping on the bottom and not open all the way. If i dont, the studs in the walls will be leaning past their center of mass, and the walls perpendicular to the slope will be angled to be square to the sloped walls. the windows looking angled is something i can live with, the floors and ceiling collapsing i cannot live through.

Do I *need* to plumb the walls? I'm on a time crunch but I don't want to be too stupid. Is the weight of a ceiling + 40 lbs enough that I should still be concerned with the load bearing capabilities of non-vertical stud walls?

Comment: Are you talking about leveling the tops of some walls? "Plumb" is for aligning things with vertical.

Comment: From "building a small room," I inferred that this room was contained within a larger structure. Then you mention 3/4" plywood and sheathing, so I infer that this is a freestanding structure. Can you better clarify what exactly you're building? Can you better clarify what exactly you've already built?

Comment: Plumb doesn’t cost money or much time. Why would this even be a consideration?

Comment: Not sure how plumb walls relates to ceilings....?

Comment: And if money is an issue, why are you splashing out on thicker-than-normal drywall and sheathing?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. It sounds like you're building a bomb-proof wall for some reason. Why would you not toss a bubble level against it before you fasten it in place? Are you asking whether your walls need to be a parallelogram such that the studs are all vertical? "Building a room" implies adding a room to an existing structure. Is that the case, or are you building a new _building_?

Comment: Re reading the question, the floor is not level.  The walls can be plumb, but not square.  Two walls will need to be out of square if all walls are plumb, or two walls must be out of plumb if all the walls are square.  One or two degrees off of level should not be major.  Doors/windows should be on squared walls, plumb can be faked a bit.

Comment: I think the question is: I have a floor that slopes and can't fix it. Should I frame the walls perpendicular to the floor or plumb. If I plumb the walls, a door may not open correctly because the upward-sloping floor may interfere with the bottom of the door.